# Angulardart: Replacement for ng-repeat-start?

Tags: angularjs, dart, angular-dart

I'm trying to iterate over a list.

```
<table>
  <tr ng-repeat='x in list' is='mycomponent' x='x'></tr>
</table>
```

But some values in the list needs to be displayed on multiple rows.
I would like to solve this by using ng-repeat-start, or rather making the tr into a component that could be more then one TR.

```
<table>
  <mycomponent ng-repeat='x in list' x='x'></mycomponent>
<table>
```

But thats not working..

How should i solve this?

Comment: @pixelbits its actually a sub-list inside the list that decides how many rows it should add. I will update my question a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Solved this by putting the repeat on a `<tbody>` instead.

```
<table>
  <tbody ng-repeat='x in list'>
    <tr x='x' is='mycomponent'></tr>
    <tr ng-repeat='y in x.sublist'></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```